# get_option array value defaults and best practices

Tags: options, settings-api

I have a custom options page.
I have several sections of settings and some of them are even more closely related to each other so I decided to store them in arrays, seems more logical to me. It surely, minimizes the code a bit too.
First question: Is this a good practice?

Example:

```
get_option('header')['header_logo']['image'];
get_option('header')['header_logo']['width'];
get_option('header')['header_logo']['height'];
get_option('header')['header_color'];
```

This results to an array which includes nested arrays at different levels.
If we use `get_option('header');` normally and supposedly store a string, we can use `get_option('header', 'default value');` to echo a default value if the option is not set. How can I do this for a value within an array ex. `get_option('header')['header_logo'];` and similarly for `get_option('header')['header_logo']['image'];`? Also how can this be done for all items in the whole array at once?

Second question: Which is the best practice when it comes to setting default option values? Should I use the `update_option` function in the `after_theme_setup` function to set the defaults? Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First question: Is this a good practice?

Based on the type of value you are saving, array as settings value is definitely good practice.

---

### How can I do this for a value within an array ex. `get_option('header')['header_logo']['image']`?

If you believe option value for `header` might be empty or not saved, you can use this -

```php
get_option( 
  'header', 
  array( 
    'header_logo' => array(
      'image' => '.../default-image.png',
      'width' => '200',
      'height' => '60'
    )
  )
)['header_logo']['image']
```

However, if the option `header` contains any value (even empty array), then the above option will not override the default. In that case, you could write a wrapper function for `get_option` function.

```php
function wpse_get_header_settings( $group = '', $key = '', $default = null ) {

  $settings = get_option( 'header' );

  $defaults = array( 
    'header_logo' => array(
      'image' => '.../default-image.png',
      'width' => '200',
      'height' => '60'
    )
  );

  $settings = wp_parse_args( $settings, $defaults );

  if ( ! empty( $group ) ) {
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $group, $settings ) ) {
      return $default;
    }

    $settings = $settings[ $group ];

    if ( ! empty( $key ) ) {
      return array_key_exists( $key, $settings ) ? $settings[ $key ] : $default;
    }
  }

  return $settings;
}
```

And then, you can safely get any desired value -

```php
// would return the logo image
echo wpse_get_header_settings( 'header_logo', 'image' );

// would return the header text color
wpse_get_header_settings( 'header_color' );
```

---

### Which is the best practice when it comes to setting default option values?

It's better to save default option values using `after_theme_setup` for theme and `register_activation_hook` for plugin. But, if you use a wrapper function to call settings, you shouldn't save it.

Comment: Shazzad, thank you very much this is a great answer. I am glad you've showed me the wrapper function in any case, however isn't this function unnecessary if I set defaults after theme setup?

Comment: Yes, it's unnecessary if you set defaults after theme setup.

Comment: Am I right to say that you can get rid of possible error/warnings such as "illegal string" when using arrays by updating options with default values?

Comment: Definitely. if called property exists within array, no warning will be given.